# Swift - Prevent creating two reference of class

Tags: ios, swift

I have app delegate which is a single point in app. Also I've created `ApplicationManager` class which is a part of app delegate now.

so what I want to achieve is to protect my code from other developers to be used in a wrong way.

So let's say my `ApplicationManager` looks like this:

```
class ApplicationManager {

    var api: API?

    static func instance() -> ApplicationManager {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            fatalError()
        }
        return appDelegate.applicationManager
    }
}
```

I want to make sure that used will use ApplicationManager via:

`let am = ApplicationManager.instance()` but not like this `am = ApplicationManager()` which will create one more manager which I don't want.

is there a way to show build time error? or drop some message? or crash in crash in case there are more that one `ApplicationManager` in app =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply make your `init` private:

```
private init() {}
```

Also, the singleton pattern would be usually implemented simply as:

```
static let shared = ApplicationManager()
```

Called as `ApplicationManager.shared`. If you want `AppDelegate` to create the instance, `private init` won't work.